# How do I put hamburger icon on next line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a line of menu tabs below which there is a line of breadcrumbs. When the screen collapses the line of menu tabs is replaced by the hamburger icon on the right, which is correct. However, in bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha 6 the hamburger icon dropped down onto the line of breadcrumbs but in version 4.1.3 it stays on its own line. Is there any way in 4.1.3 that I can force the previous behaviour? Displaying 2 lines instead of 1 is a waste of space, and on a small screen this is annoying. Here is a code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Put hamburger icon onto breadcrumb line</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<h1>Put hamburger icon onto breadcrumb line</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand"></span>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-tabs mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #6</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #7</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #8</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #9</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Crumb #1</a>
  <span class="breadcrumb-item active">Crumb #2</span>
 <span class="breadcrumb-item active">Crumb #3</span>
</nav>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the icon to be within the breadcrumb container, or just beside it?

Comment: @Keno Clayton - I would prefer the icon to be within the breadcrumb container, just like it was with version 4.0.0 alpha 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this suit your needs?

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: -44px;
  }

  .breadcrumb {
     padding-right: 66px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1>Put hamburger icon onto breadcrumb line</h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
      <span class="navbar-brand"></span>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-tabs mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #5</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #6</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #7</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #8</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #9</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab #10</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="breadcrumb">
      <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Crumb #1</a>
      <span class="breadcrumb-item active">Crumb #2</span>
      <span class="breadcrumb-item active">Crumb #3</span>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
```

Comment: Without the margin-right in the breadcrumb class this does exactly what I want, thanks.

Comment: @TonyMarston I have edited my answer to fit the "without the margin-right in the breadcrumb" specification.